# How to center a cell in the aligned environment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, amsmath, aligned

I want to center an equation inside a cell in the aligned environment from the `amsmath` package.

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\boxed{\begin{aligned}
\mbox{Therefore, one plus one equals two.}\\
1+1=2
\end{aligned}}$
\end{document}
```

and it produces

[image]

To be clear, I want `1+1=2` to be centered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you switch from an `aligned` to a `gathered` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\boxed' macro and 'gathered' env.
\begin{document}
$\boxed{\begin{gathered}
        \textnormal{Therefore, one plus one equals two.}\\
        1+1=2
        \end{gathered}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! May I ask why you use inline math mode instead of display math mode?

Comment: @Pseudonym123 - The code you posted originally didn't contain any switch to math mode, and hence wasn't compilable since `\boxed` must occur in math mode. I just chose the simpler of the two available options. For sure, your code (and mine -- the only difference being in the use of `aligned` and `gathered` environments) works equally well in either math mode.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you switch from an `aligned` to TeX primitive `\halign`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\boxed{\vbox{\halign{\hfil#\hfil\cr
Therefore, one plus one equals two.\cr
$1+1=2$\cr}}}

\end{document}
```